# Can hand wrenches and sockets be cleaned in a sonic cleaner?

Tags: tools, cleaning

Since tools are a big part of motor vehicle repair I've run across some old hand wrenches and sockets that have rust on them and I'd like to keep them but wanted them cleaned. I was curious, due to the amount of surface rust if hand tools be cleaned with a [sonic cleaner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007TNX9ZE) such as:

[image]

I've debated a solution of [simple green](https://www.uline.com/BL_6974/Simple-Green), alcohol and a little water. Leave them in for a few hours or until clean but I'm unsure of any metal weakening or damaging to the finish or if it's suggested?

Answer (score 1):

For surface rust and more you could make an electrolysis bath.

Easy using a wall wart or old computer laptop power block, just make sure the output is dc...

Water with a teaspoon of salt and then a couple of hours works wonders...

Best is you can use a larger plastic container as most spanners won’t fit in that sonic thing - it’s designed for small personal items ie earrings watches etc...

Baesd on comments:
Do this in a well-ventilated area or put the bath outside...

The amount if chlorine released will be small based on the teaspoon of salt... see https://orbitingfrog.com/2014/11/02/electrolysis-of-water-with-pencils-and-a-9v-battery/

Comment: I recommend soda, since salt could release chlorine gas.

Comment: You will probably get a higher concentration at the local pool... putting the bath in a well ventilated area or, better, outside...